# String split in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to split a column and have to create two new other columns in microsoft sql server.

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Why tag `MySQL` when you are asking is for `SQL Server`?

Comment: This may not be duplicate question as the OP I am guessing is looking for something like compute columns. There is need for data materialization, not only formatting it on read, which in the context of SQL Server maybe even computed persisted column in terms of performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a hack using `parsename`

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('120/20','/','.'),2) as SP, 
PARSENAME(REPLACE('120/20','/','.'),1) as DP
```

Output

```
SP DP
120 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALTER to do that.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name data_type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create [computed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) columns in case you are not allowed or able to populate the columns on write/update:

```
CREATE TABLE DataSource 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
   ,BPValue VARCHAR(12)
)

GO

INSERT INTO DataSource (ID, BPValue)
VALUES (1, '123/98')
      ,(2, '118/72')
      ,(3, '97/74');

GO

ALTER TABLE DataSource
ADD Value1 AS TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(BPValue, 0, CHARINDEX('/', BPValue)) AS INT)

ALTER TABLE DataSource
ADD Value2 AS TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(BPValue, CHARINDEX('/', BPValue) + 1, 128) AS INT)


GO

SELECT *
FROM DataSource
```

[image]

Also, the columns can be materialized if you create them with the `PERSISTED` option. Otherwise, the computation is perform on read, which can be slow on certain cases.

The better way, is to create two separate columns and populate the data on insert/update.

---

The above can be [done on MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifretB9SWasr5erFcwv148/0), too. Here is the link to the [official](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) documentation.